# nrf52 with nrf sdk (not nrf-connect!) 15.2 on vscode - intellisense issue

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, embedded, intellisense

I'll start with the dry details:
Host system : ubuntu 22.04
vs code 1.80.2
the project:
embedded for nrf52840 processor using nrf sdk 15.2 and gcc arm toolchain : gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update.
the project is copiled using makefile the makefile takes the sdk dir from env variable and in nrf-sdk the toolchain is taken from configuration file inside the sdk.

this is my c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
"env": {
    "nrfSDK": "/home/eyal/develop/sdks/nRF5_SDK_15.2.0_9412b96/"
},
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "nrf52",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "${nrfSDK}/components",
            "${nrfSDK}/components/softdevice/common",
            "${nrfSDK}/components/softdevice/s140/headers",
            "${nrfSDK}/components/softdevice/s140/headers/nrf52",
            "${nrfSDK}/components/toolchain/cmsis/include",
            "${nrfSDK}/components/libraries/**",
            "${nrfSDK}/components/boards",
            "${nrfSDK}/modules/**",
            "${nrfSDK}/modules/",
            "${nrfSDK}/integration/nrfx",
            "${nrfSDK}/integration/nrfx/legacy",
            "${nrfSDK}/external/**"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "BOARD_PCA10056",
            "BSP_DEFINES_ONLY",
            "CONFIG_GPIO_AS_PINRESET",
            "FLOAT_ABI_HARD",
            "NRF52840_XXAA"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "/home/eyal/develop/sdks/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++14",
        "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-arm",
        "compilerArgs": [
            "-O3",
            "-g3",
            "-mcpu=cortex-m4",
            "-mthumb",
            "-mabi=aapcs",
            "-Wall -Werror",
            "-mfloat-abi=hard ",
            "-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16",
            "-ffunction-sections",
            "-fdata-sections",
            "-fno-strict-aliasing",
            "-fno-builtin",
            "-fshort-enums"
        ]
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

I'm using blinky example so have only one main.c file.
files that exists in the includepath i have defined are directed just fine if i ask vscode to go to definition. But everything that is related to the path of libraries that arrive with the compiler - i can see that vscode takes me to clang directories of the host!
I have verified that when vscode is started the arm-gcc file is called and ouputs all flags, const and include path, so the plugin does do it's job, but something goes bad along the way, anyone with vscode experience can help ?
i thought maybe i need to change system include path in settings.json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nice that no 1 has answered, either not too many are using VSCODE or no one really knows how to configure it and just dumbly follow insturctions.

Problems solved by turning on all logs and seeing that the compiler could not run as two commands in my argument defs are joined by a space and vscode does not know how to pass it well.

Separating them solved the issue and now the system path is the right one.